# Optimal configuration for background scan - Android / AltBeacon

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

My goal is to provide a new means of communication to merchants. These merchants will seize their ads on a platform and the beacons will take care of "spreading" them.

The mobile application will therefore scan the beacons on the background (the most frequent case) and retrieve merchants' ads based on the ids of the discovered beacons. So I need a very regular scan so that no ads are missed.

I have already done a big part of the development however I do not know how to configure the periods of scans.

What optimal configuration would you advise me for this case ?

Currently the application to this configuration in background: setBackgroundScanPeriod(2000L); setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0L);

The foreground setting is the default setting. So I scan for two seconds and then start again immediately.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The default settings of the AndroidBeaconLibrary are already optimized for fast background detections on Android 5+ devices** when using the `BackgroundPowerSaver`.

When no beacons have yet been detected, the library will do a constant low-power scan for beacons when in the background.  This yields **detections within 5 seconds** on tested Nexus or Pixel devices.

This relies on hardware filters which do not work on Android 4.3 and 4.4 devices and will not work if beacons are already in the vicinity.  For these cases, background scanning falls back to cycles of 10 seconds scanning every 3000 seconds.

While you are welcome to increase the on/off cycle rate from 10/3000 to something more frequent, the 2000/0 ratio you suggest will drain the battery on users devices noticably, so I recommend against it.

**The defaults are designed to give optimal performance for most use cases**.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, so for my utilisation you would let the config by default?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I would leave the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on the capability of the device and importantly how much battery do you not mind draining. The faster the polling the more draining of the device battery. You also have to keep in mind that the iBeacons also have a interval of sending scans which also drains battery.

For example I have set some iBeacons to a frequency of 900ms and they still are at 100% battery after 1 week. So it seems like you can max out the iBeacons, but as the android application goes you have to see how the battery drainage goes with higher polling rates.